# Continue while loop when the function catches exception

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch, continue

I have multiple functions inside a `while` loop. Each of these functions has a `try/except` block to catch `Exception`. Basically, my while loop is perpetual, so if one of my functions catches an `Exception`, I would like to `continue` the loop, i.e. go back to the top of the loop. How can this be done, please?

As I have many functions that are called within the while loop, I prefer not to have the `try/except` blocks outside the functions as I would have so many blocks inside the main loop (or script).

Comment: Please post a [mre] of your code so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Can you please post a snippet so we can know where to help you @QFI, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you would have to surround your functions in your while loop with a try/except block.

If the functions themselves have a try/except block within them and they are still being raised as errors in your while loop, I would assume your try/except block in your functions are not robust enough and it is not catching all the possible exceptions/errors.